# python-packaging: share build-backend between requirements and my package

Tags: python, installation, packaging, setup.py, python-packaging

I have several dependecies for my python pyackage. Two of those requirements are prophet (https://github.com/facebook/prophet) and george (https://github.com/dfm/george). The problem with those packages is, that they require installing numpy, pybind11 and other packages before the installation since they are used during the build process. However, I want to make it as easy as possible for the user without prior installation of several packages.

Packages that are required for building a package can be specified with setup_requires in setup.py or in [build-system] inside pyproject.toml. I thought I would be able to achieve a single command installation with "pip install" by specyfing those build requirements of the external package in my pyproject.toml. However, this doesn´t work. My suggestion is, that for each package for which a wheel has to be build a separate build-backend is used. Therefore the build requirements aren´t located when building the third party package.

I found almost no documentation for build-backend and build requirements. Can you anyone give me a hint?

I have a minimum working example here: https://github.com/FelixKleineBoesing/pypackagingdemo
With docker installed you can start the building process with:

```
docker build .
```

Without line 10, pip isn´t able to successfully build george since numpy and pybind11 are missing.

Full traceback:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  81.41kB
Step 1/8 : FROM python:3.7
 ---> 34a518642c76
Step 2/8 : RUN mkdir /buildbackend
 ---> Running in 38e398f63eed
Removing intermediate container 38e398f63eed
 ---> f88b7b3f4056
Step 3/8 : COPY ./abctest /buildbackend/abctest
 ---> 5976a8f6d708
Step 4/8 : COPY ./pyproject.toml /buildbackend/pyproject.toml
 ---> 73d4bb506910
Step 5/8 : COPY ./setup.py /buildbackend/setup.py
 ---> 0a377986a29d
Step 6/8 : COPY ./Manifest.in /buildbackend/Manifest.in
 ---> c30e903f8f84
Step 7/8 : RUN cd /buildbackend && pip3 install .
 ---> Running in 7925fc1a9a45
Processing /buildbackend
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
Collecting george>=0.3.1 (from abctest==0.0.1)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/27/19/9de575be629e3a41c3ca6b1e2c80e0ae90a2e831436c5f70cc8d72e37ab7/george-0.3.1.tar.gz (1.8MB)
Collecting numpy (from george>=0.3.1->abctest==0.0.1)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/63/0c/0261693cc3ad8e2b66e66dc2d2676a2cc17d3efb1c58a70db73754320e47/numpy-1.18.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting scipy (from george>=0.3.1->abctest==0.0.1)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dd/82/c1fe128f3526b128cfd185580ba40d01371c5d299fcf7f77968e22dfcc2e/scipy-1.4.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (26.1MB)
Collecting pybind11 (from george>=0.3.1->abctest==0.0.1)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4b/4d/ae1c4d8e8b139afa9682054dd42df3b0e3b5c1731287933021b9fd7e9cc4/pybind11-2.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: abctest
  Building wheel for abctest (PEP 517): started
  Building wheel for abctest (PEP 517): finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-5ruh8xv_/wheels/e3/5f/a4/652949565a7089970182a50f7eec733873579b601c20f0cb97
Successfully built abctest
Building wheels for collected packages: george
  Building wheel for george (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for george (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-bijmj8ct/george/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-i9_120mu --python-tag cp37:
  ERROR: running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/george
  copying george/kernels.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/george
  copying george/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/george
  copying george/gp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/george
  copying george/modeling.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/george
  copying george/metrics.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/george
  copying george/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/george
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/george/solvers
  copying george/solvers/basic.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/george/solvers
  copying george/solvers/trivial.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/george/solvers
  copying george/solvers/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/george/solvers
  copying george/solvers/hodlr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/george/solvers
  running egg_info
  writing george.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to george.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to george.egg-info/requires.txt
  writing top-level names to george.egg-info/top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'george.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  writing manifest file 'george.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  copying george/kernel_interface.cpp -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/george
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/george/include
  copying george/include/.DS_Store -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/george/include
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/george/include/george
  copying george/include/george/exceptions.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/george/include/george
  copying george/include/george/george.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/george/include/george
  copying george/include/george/hodlr.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/george/include/george
  copying george/include/george/kernels.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/george/include/george
  copying george/include/george/metrics.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/george/include/george
  copying george/include/george/parser.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/george/include/george
  copying george/include/george/subspace.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/george/include/george
  copying george/solvers/_hodlr.cpp -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/george/solvers
  running build_ext
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-install-bijmj8ct/george/setup.py", line 231, in <module>
      zip_safe=True,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 145, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 192, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 78, in run
      _build_ext.run(self)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-bijmj8ct/george/setup.py", line 105, in build_extensions
      import numpy
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for george
  Running setup.py clean for george
Failed to build george
Installing collected packages: numpy, scipy, pybind11, george, abctest
  Running setup.py install for george: started
```

Comment: you can't use both `setup.py` and `pyproject.toml`, it's the first if you want to use setuptools / pip and the second if you want to use flit / poetry. Either way, numpy and pybind are not part of the build backend, you need to look into the documentation of the tools you're using to learn how they want you to specify dependencies. It might also be a good idea to read up a bit more [on python packaging](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/), or use `poetry new <project name>` to generate a working minimal example for you.

Comment: Hey @Arne, thanks for your answer. I can´t or shouldn´t mix setup.py and pyproject.toml? Technically, it is possible to use both in combination. I looked this up in several documentations and guides but found no clue. The URL you mentioned isn´t really helping me as it only states general information on packaging. I was searching for a solution to this specific problem. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You shouldn't, they will contain the same information in different formats, you should just pick the packaging tool that you want to use (pip, flit, hatch, poetry, ..) and then see what that tool expects. Just so you have a starting point, maybe give poetry a shot: https://python-poetry.org/docs/basic-usage/

Comment: Got it. :) Let´s assume the pyproject.toml doesn´t exist and the build requirements are defined in setup_requires inside the setup.py. That still wouldn´t help me, since numpy and pybind11 are only existing for the building of my package, but not for my dependencies, right? Is the consequence, that I have to rely on updates of third party packages that they are getting rid of the problem that packages may not be already installed when installing their package? Or is there any workaround?. I already looked things up in the docs of poetry and flit, but there´s is also nothing that would help me.

Comment: I know that this would annul the deterministic and reproducible build of packages since I would inject dependencies into the build process that aren´t specified by the third-party-package itself.

Comment: @Felix @Arne As far as I know there is absolutely nothing wrong about having both `setup.py` and `pyproject.toml` and this case looks like a perfectly good example of that. In my quick test the build seemed to work without any issue. What is the problem exactly? Is there any error message?

Comment: @sinoroc Thanks you your answer. I edited the original post and appended the docker build log. As you can see, the library george is trying to import nunpy to get the numpy header for their own compilation of some pyx/c files. Therefore george can be installed, but some parts of george aren´t successfully compiled.

Comment: Thanks, it helps getting a better understanding of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like the packaging of the *george* project is somewhat faulty and can not be built cleanly without pre-installing *numpy* first (as you do in the `Dockerfile`). Probably if this project were to use the `build-system` feature of `pyproject.toml` (*PEP 517*) and add `numpy` to its list of `requires` then it would build without issue.

As an alternative one could consider pre-building their own *wheels* of the `george` project and cache/share them for later reuse. In the case of *Docker* there are good solutions for this.

Comment: Exactly. I have already created a pull request for George that will be merged whenever a dependency of George will be fixed. In the meanwhile I created a base docker image. But my questions is, whether there exists a solution to fix my problem inside the pip environment.

Comment: I don't think there's much else you can do, but help the maintainers of the project improve the user experience (fix the build or publish _wheel_ distributions on _PyPI_). On the other hand I would really look into building the _wheels_ properly, cache them somewhere, and then reuse them for the following deployments. Which is the right thing to do anyway, with or without the original build issue.

Comment: @FelixKleineBösing Does that answer your question? Any clarification needed?